# jQuery Vertical Tabs making tab content display as inline-block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I'm using jQuery tabs, and recently switched to the vertical tabs, and I noticed the content is not placed "inside" the space after the tabs. Its placed inside a container div that has a margin that way it appears to be inside that content box. This does not work well for a responsive design.

Example screenshot:
[image]

**The orange is the margin.**

I figured out by adding `display: inline-block` to each tab, I can get the content to be contained in the space after the tabs. I want to know how to add this dynamically instead of placing an inline style in every tab's div.

Here is the example of the HTML for my tabs:

```
<div id="tabs-1" style="display: inline-block">
    <div id="placeholder" class="chart-resize"></div>
    <div id="placeholder2" class="chart-resize"></div>
</div>

<div id="tabs-2" style="display: inline-block">
    <div id="placeholder3" class="chart-resize"></div>
    <div id="placeholder4" class="chart-resize"></div>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery part for vertical tabs:

```
$("#tabs").tabs().addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");
$("#tabs li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
```

All styles in jQueryUI.css are default.

Comment: Define a class to use as a selector, e.g: `<div id="tabs-1" class="tab-content">...</div>`, an example of a css selector to add your style declarations to: `.tab-content { display: inline-block; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a class with `display: inline-block` as an attribute and adding it to each tab does not work because you are then overriding the inactive tabs styles setting the inactive tab's content to have `display: inline-block` as well, so all the content of every tab appears all in one.

Instead, I did some fiddling and found a CSS class in the jQuery UI stylesheet that you can **change the display attribute from the default of `display: block` to `display: inline-block`**. This allows the content to actually be contained "inside" that tabs content square, creating a more responsive design.

Here is the class:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 0;
    padding: 1em 1.4em;
    background: 0 0
}
```